# Unit Testing DbContext For Entities Having List<string> Properties

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-6, .net-6.0, xunit

I have entities in my `DbContext` which contain properties of type `List<string>`, which is a valid way to store data in `Postgres` as `text[]`.

```
Tags = table.Column<List<string>>(type: "text[]", nullable: false),
```

---

```
public List<string> Tags { get; set; } = new List<string>();
```

---

Xunit Startup class defines my `DbContext` as:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>((builder) =>
{
    builder.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
}).BuildServiceProvider();
```

---

Any attempt to interact with `DbSet<T>` where `T` contains a property with type `List<string>` this exception is thrown:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : The entity type 'List<string>' requires a primary key to be defined. 
If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'.
```

How can you define `HasNoKey` on a `List<string>`? Should I be initializing my `DbContext` for unit testing a different way?

Answer (score 0):

After some further digging I came up with this, which seems to handle things for now until I get into testing `Tags` being stored:

```
public class TestMyDbContext : MyDbContext
{
    public TestMyDbContext(DbContextOptions options) 
        : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<EntityOne>().Ignore(x => x.Tags);
        builder.Entity<EntityTwo>().Ignore(x => x.Tags);
        ...
    }
}
```

and then in my xunit `Startup.cs` file I inject my `DbContext` like this:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext, TestMyDbContext>(builder) =>
{
    builder.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
}).BuildServiceProvider();
```

I'm sure this is just one of many limitations to `UseInMemoryDatabase()` for unit tests, but `.Ignore()` for properties that it can't manage seems like a decent workaround.